# External js file not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, external

Good afternoon/evening everyone

Why in mobile browsers (Chrome Mobile, Kiwi) the external `js` file is not visible in the html file ?

**script.js :**

```
alert('hello from script');
```

Next I try to include this file in html code with

```
<script src="script.js">
</script>
```

(both files are in the same folder)

This code only works on desktop, but doesn't work on mobile browser
I tried to determine the full path with :

```
output.innerText = location.href;
```

And then copied it to the `src` attribute :

```
<p id="output">
</p>  
<script src="content://com.estrongs.files/storage/emulated/0/my_files/other/js/test%20script%20src/script.js">
 //output.innerText = location.href;
</script>
```

Still doesn't work!
I've tried all kinds of ways: `'./sript.js'` and `type="text/javascript"` also doesn't help

What else can be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer

I figured out what's up

I have installed Termux and local server NodeJS, wrote a simple script

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
var folder = '';

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, folder)));

app.listen(8080, function ()
 {
  console.log("Server is running on port 8080.");
 });
```

Now all tags with the attribute work correctly "src=..." (`<script src="...">, <img src="...">, <link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`)

All you have to do is type in the address bar of your browser:

localhost:8080/path to my .html